# Proving whether $1.117 * n^2 * \sqrt{n} \in O(\log \log n)$ is valid

Tags: computational-complexity

For starters both functions, $1.117 * n^2 * \sqrt{n}$ and $\log \log n$ for $n > 0$, increase monotonically with $n$.

Comment: If $n^{1.004}\leq Cn\log n$, then $n^{0.004}\leq C\log n$. Is this possible?

Comment: Your second last step is incorrect since K should remain in the exponent.

Comment: @Daniel That's a terrible mistake! Should've noticed it myself. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Actually, we have  $\;n\log n=o\bigl(n^{1.004}\bigr)$.

Comment: So you edited twice the question. The comments and answers are now totally unrelated...

Answer (score 1):

In going from the 3rd last line to the 2nd last line, you make an erroneous transformation. You originally had $K$ as an exponent which the rest of the expression was raised, but unjustifiably change it so that $K$ is merely multiplied by the rest of the expression. This mistake scuttles the proof.

You will find, in fact, that the statement you are trying to prove here is not true; dividing through by $n$, it's equivalent to asking whether $n^{0.117} \in O(\log n)$, which false (note that $\log n^{0.117} = 0.117 \log n$, and so, up to constant factors, we have that $\log n$ is merely logarithmic as a function of $n^{0.117}$).

Answer (score 0):

The claim is wrong. We can try to prove $n^{1.004} \in \Omega(n\log n)$. 
$$
n^{1.004} \geq C\ n \log n \Leftrightarrow \\
n^{\frac{1}{250}} \geq C \log n
$$
Now I arbitrarily set $C := 1$ and we will try to find $n_0$ such that $\forall n \geq n_0$, the inequality is respected : $n^{\frac{1}{250}} \geq \log n $. I also define $n = e^x$ for some $x > 0$. ( We assume $n$ to be "large" so this is always possible)

\begin{align}
n^{\frac{1}{250}} &\geq \log n & \Leftrightarrow \\
e^{\frac{x}{250}} &\geq x & \Leftrightarrow\\
\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{(\frac{x}{250})^i}{i!} &\geq x & \overset{(*)}{\Leftarrow} \\
\frac{(\frac{x}{250})^2}{2!} &\geq x & \Leftrightarrow  \\
\frac{x^2}{2\cdot 250^2} & \geq x & \Leftrightarrow \\
x &\geq 2\cdot 250^2 & \Leftrightarrow \\
e^x &\geq e^{2\cdot 250^2} & \Leftrightarrow \\
n & \geq e^{2\cdot 250^2}
\end{align}
$(*)$ The sum contains only positive terms. We keep only the one when $i=2$.

Hence when $n \geq e^{2\cdot 250^2}$ we have that $n^{1.004} \geq n \log n$